# How to prevent htmlspecialchars (PHP) to conver integer in string

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a web application where some data, stored in a database, is displayed in a div.

Since this data comes from the user, in order to prevent any javascript injection I want to use the htmlspecialchars() function for each single value extracted from the database before building my web page.
I am using the following function to iterate through the arrays of data that I get from the database.

```
function filter(&$arr) {

         foreach ($arr as $key => &$val) {
            if (is_array($val)){
                $this->filter($val);
            }else{
                $val=htmlspecialchars($val);
            }
         } 

     }
```

But when the array of data is processed by this function the integer values are converted in to string.

Is there a way to prevent this conversion?

I prefere to have the integer as integer because part of the data is elaborated by javascript and some part of the code does not work properly if data are supplied as string. I am looking for a generic solution that can be applied no matter what type of data comes from the database.

Comment: Do you store arrays in your database? (assuming from your code)

Comment: @martinweise Most likely each array contains a row from the query result.

Comment: Instead of using such a generic conversion function you should apply the `htmlspecialchars()` function only where it makes sense: when hydrating the template. There it does not matter at all if the results are strings or integers, since html does not know about the data type. And it prevents you from having to deal with escaped characters in conditionals and the like. This actually is more secure, since you keep the application at one place, regardless of where the data comes from that you use to hydrate your templates.

Comment: Have you tested that it's not coming out of the DB as a string?

Comment: Each array is a row from the database. The problem does not come from the database because I checked the array before it has been processed and it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
} else if (!is_int($val)) {
    $val = htmlspecialchars($val);
}
```

this won't be a security risk as if it's really an int it can not contain injections...

Comment: I was looking for a more generic solution becase the same problem could happend with double and may be other type of data.

Comment: @Linden it looks like the available option on the table is what you have proposed. I whill use your metod but with a small modification, I will apply the cleaning only on string using is_string, in this way the other type of data will not be affected. A javascript injection must be a string, so I will check only data of type string.